# Area 51 referrer notification shouldn't be showing when I'm the referrer, or when I'm already commited

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, area-51, referrals

I followed a link to the [Workplace Area 51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30887/the-workplace) that contained my referrer code, and was greeted by this lovely notification:

> **Welcome to Stack Exchange Area 51!**
>
> **Yannis Rizos** thought you'd be interested in this proposed Q&A site. If you like the idea, you can click the "Commit" button below to be notified when the site is created.

Well, I know that already ;)

It would also make sense (?) that the notification doesn't appear when the visitor is already committed.

[image]

In other news, the Workplace proposal finally reached 100% commitment, yay!

Comment: Man, I would have thought the Programmers veterans would know better than to relive those "growing pains" all over again on a new site. :-)

Comment: @TheEstablishment Funny you should mention it, A P.SE mod proposed the site and quite a few P.SE mods are committed (including all mods, if I'm not horribly mistaken). I don't know if the site will survive beta, but I think none of us wants it to be the toilet bowl P.SE used to be. Will just have to wait and see on this one, I really don't know if the P.SE experience will prove useful, hurtful or completely irrelevant.

Comment: There is a small window. I tested it--i was able to commit to Workplace. Site looks interesting, so I'll keep the commitment..

Comment: @ManishEarth Yeap, three others committed as well, so I've removed that from the question. It kinda makes sense, there would be no point in restricting more people from committing before the private beta actually begins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We show it to you so that you can see what it looks like, otherwise there's no easy way for you to know what people are seeing when you send them the link.

We *could* hide it after you've committed, but I can't see it as a big problem that it shows up.  At least it's consistent.

Comment: Obviously not a big problem, and probably not something that will come up a lot, I guess it's not really common to click a link that has your referral code in it. 11 more people committed after I posted this, and that's way cooler than removing a silly notification.